# Compatibility with PSN

Tags: psn

If I buy a game on my PS3 such as Chrono Trigger that is Compatible with both the PS3 system and the PSP/Vita system. Will I be able to play on both the PSP/Vita and the PS3? If so, can I transfer saves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

But the saves will not automatically transfer, you ll have to transfer it manually everytime you switch from PS3/4/Vita to another.

Source: Playing FF6 PSN on PS3 and PS Vita.

Comment: +1, but I'd like to add that some games (such as the FFX/X-2 HD collection, MGS: Peace Walker) have their own built-in save utilities to transfer saves.

Comment: Thoses are games for PS3/4/Vita with cross save utilities, I am talking of PSN games (PS1/2 made for PS3/4/Vita), like Chrono Trigger

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if the game supports cross-buy. It's starting to become more rare but some PS3/Vita games are indeed separate. Most games now are cross-buy, it will tell you in the item description.